# return type of annotate

Tags: django, django-annotate

I want to get date when first order was placed for each item in database.

If I use this:

```
event_queryset3 = OrderItemTable.objects.filter(filter).annotate(f_date=Min(f_date_ord))
```

this will give dates only for items which has been ordered.

If I use this:

```
event_queryset3 = OrderItemTable.objects.annotate(f_date=Min(f_date_ord, filter=filter))
```

this gives desired date (first order date) for all items but in **'str' type** which I can not use.

Can anyone help please. My variables rae:

```
filter = Q(prev_order_items__order_id__order_type='Normal') & Q(prev_order_items__order_id__final_approval='Yes')


f_date_ord = F('prev_order_items__order_id__created_at')
```

Comment: And what is your question?

Comment: @DanielRoseman, I have updated the question, I want first date for all items in datetime.date formate not str.

Comment: What's the field type of `f_date_ord`?

Comment: @Tsang-YiShen, type of f_date_ord is datetime.date.